# How to initialize host machine on GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am using Kubernetes on Google Container Engine.

I want to run an arbitrary script on each host machine when a cluster is created/resized to initialize its configuration.  How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible to do in an automated fashion today. You can write a script and ssh into each of your machines after you create your cluster but that won't work if the cluster is resized.